# Condition for a general third degree polyomial to a have a particular second degree polynomial as a factor

Tags: polynomials

Hi I have a question that I just cannot answer so I would be very great full for some help :)

If $x^2 +ax-1$ is a factor of $x^3+px^2+qx+r$ show that $q=-(ar+1)$

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  In order for MathJax commands to be effective, they must be surrounded by `$` signs.  For example, `$x^2$` shows up as $x^2$.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: What happens if you perform long division of the cubic polynomial by the quadratic polynomial?

Comment: I tried long division but it didn’t work out so I then used unknown coefficients and that worked out in the end .Thanks so much for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since both leading coefficients equal $1$ we know that for some number $s$ it is the case that

$$ (x^2+ax-1)(x-s)=x^3+px^2+qx+r $$

Multiplying the polynomials on the right gives

$$  x^3+(a-s)x^2-(1+as)x+s=x^3+px^2+qx+r$$

The coefficients of equal powers must be equal. Therefore

- $p=a-s$

  $q=-(1+as)$

  $r=s$

  Since $r=s$ we have $q=-(1+ar)$

Comment: Thank you so much !!

Answer (score 1):

Let $\alpha, \beta $ be the roots of the first polynomial, and $\gamma$ the remaining root of the second polynomial. We need to compute

$q = \alpha\beta+\beta\gamma +\gamma\alpha = \alpha\beta + \gamma(\alpha + \beta)$.

We know that

$\alpha + \beta = -a$

$\alpha\beta = -1$

$\gamma = \frac {-r}{\alpha \beta} = r$

Thus $q = \alpha\beta + \gamma(\alpha + \beta) = -1 - ar=-(ar+1)$

Comment: Thank you I finally got it after trying a couple of methods !!